# Workarounds for TensorFlow (and Keras) on RStudio Server Pro Version 1.2.5033-1

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, rstudio

Does anyone know how to use [`tensorflow`](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/) in RStudio Cloud without running into [this known fatal error](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6049)? Are there versions of Python, Miniconda, TensorFlow, and Keras that make it work? My current setup script is [here](https://github.com/wlandau/learndrake/blob/master/inst/notebooks/rstudio-cloud-setup.R).

I use an [RStudio Cloud project](https://rstudio.cloud/project/627076) to teach a [workshop](https://github.com/wlandau/learndrake). I am running into the known bug described [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6049) and [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/trouble-setting-up-tensorflow-on-rstudio-cloud/52349), and it is only a matter of time before the amazing folks at RStudio release a new IDE with a patch. But in the meantime, I have several workshops to teach, and I cannot install a different version of the IDE on Cloud. Cloud would be perfect if I can get it to work.

I already posted [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/trouble-setting-up-tensorflow-on-rstudio-cloud/52349) about this, but I am trying to cast a wider net to see if anyone found a clever workaround.

Comment: I don't use RStudio, but ... can you put it in a `future` and let it run possibly without `rstudioapi`-stuff hanging around?

Comment: What an awesome idea! Just tried ` callr::r(function() tensorflow::tf_config())` and it worked! I will have to try it on the rest of the workshop.

Comment: I also had thought about `processx` (and therefore `callr`) but wondered if it would be easier (data transfer) to keep it as a `future` so that the serialization is more natural. \*Shrug\*, whatever works. Glad it was helpful, Will.

Comment: Hmm... as I look back at more of the materials, I see how much they rely on being able to load Keras models and explore them interactively, even though the actual model fitting can be done in remote processes. What if the problem is something about `rstudioapi` like you suggested. Maybe if I could detach the package and unset some environment variables?

Comment: It's possible, I really don't know (and while I perhaps should devote the time for your workshop, I cannot this week :-). It doesn't have any DLLs, so `detach("package:rstudioapi", force=TRUE)` might work well enough (in which case I think Jonathan's [first comment](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6049#issuecomment-576428265) might be not true) . If not, I wonder if `future` will pass that package to the multi-session node. I hope `detach`ing is enough for you, that's easy enough to support for now.

Comment: Unfortunately, uninstalling the package outright does not seem to work. Nor does unsetting all the extra RStudio environment variables.

Comment: FYI, the `rstudioapi` package is not transferred in a `future`, so if that's part of the cause, then you should be able to `value(future(...))` everything. Specifically, `library(rstudioapi);sessionInfo();` shows the package but `plan(multisession);value(future(sessionInfo()));` does not.

Comment: Oddly enough, multisession futures that load `tensorflow` seem problematic in [this Cloud project](https://rstudio.cloud/project/931550). See the updated comment at https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6049#issuecomment-586091773.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! All I needed was to downgrade to TensorFlow 1.13.1. I thought I already tried that, but then I realized `install_keras()` automatically upgrades TensorFlow unless I supply a version string to the `tensorflow` argument. Here is how I set up a local Python environment with TensorFlow 1.13.1 in RStudio Cloud.

```r
reticulate::install_miniconda("miniconda")
Sys.setenv(WORKON_HOME = "virtualenvs")
reticulate::virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = "miniconda/bin/python")
keras::install_keras(
  method = "virtualenv",
  conda = "miniconda/bin/conda",
  envname = "r-reticulate",
  tensorflow = "1.13.1",
  restart_session = FALSE
)
# Now add WORKON_HOME=/cloud/project/virtualenvs to .Renviron
```